# An issue with list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have following code:

```
n=4
arr=['abcd', 'abce', 'abcdex', 'abcde']
mainarr=[{}]
dic={}
for i in range(1,n+1):
    insert(dic,arr[i-1]+' ') #insert is a function that modifies dic
    print(dic)               #to see whats the current dic
    mainarr.append(dic.copy())
```

So i get mainarr

Now the thing is that somehow the first and second elements of mainarr are same as expected, but the rest three entries are all same, and equal to the value that should have been last element of mainarr.....plz help me find whats wrong!!!

the output is

```
{'a': 'abcd '}
{'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 'abcd ', 'e': 'abce '}}}}
{'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': {' ': 'abcd ', 'e': 'abcdex '}, 'e': 'abce '}}}}
{'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': {' ': 'abcd ', 'e': {'x': 'abcdex ', ' ': 'abcde 
'}}, 'e': 'abce '}}}}
```

so the dic values are correct after each iteration

but mainarr is

```
[{}, {'a': 'abcd '}, {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': {' ': 'abcd ', 'e': {'x': 
'abcdex ', ' ': 'abcde '}}, 'e': 'abce '}}}}, {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': {' ': 
'abcd ', 'e': {'x': 'abcdex ', ' ': 'abcde '}}, 'e': 'abce '}}}}, {'a': 
{'b': {'c': {'d': {' ': 'abcd ', 'e': {'x': 'abcdex ', ' ': 'abcde '}}, 'e': 
'abce '}}}}] #as you can see, first two elements are correct, but last 3 are 
             equal to final value of dic
```

if it may help, code of insert is

```
def insert(dic,string,depth=0):
    if type(dic)==dict:

        if string[depth] in dic.keys():
            dic[string[depth]]=insert(dic[string[depth]],string,depth+1)
            return dic
        else:
            dic[string[depth]]=string
            return dic
    else:


        if dic[depth]==string[depth]:
             return {dic[depth]:insert(dic,string,depth+1)}

        else:
            return {dic[depth]:dic,string[depth]:string}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code of `insert()`?

Comment: added the code of insert()

Answer (score 0):

`dic.copy()` only copies the dictionary not its contents. You could use `copy.deepcopy` from the `copy` module instead. But there is another way move the copying into the insert function so that it always returns a copy.

Your insert function mutates the dictionary:

```
    if string[depth] in dic.keys():
        dic[string[depth]]=insert(dic[string[depth]],string,depth+1)
        return dic
    else:
        dic[string[depth]]=string
        return dic
```

If you instead copy once inside the insert function the issue disappears:

```
    dic = dic.copy()
    if string[depth] in dic.keys():
        dic[string[depth]]=insert(dic[string[depth]],string,depth+1)
        return dic
    else:
        dic[string[depth]]=string
        return dic
```

The result is that the insert function always returns a copy and then your main loop should look like this:

```
for i in range(1,n+1):
    dic = insert(dic, arr[i-1]+' ') # returns a copy that is mutated
    print(dic)               #to see whats the current dic
    mainarr.append(dic)
```